# PHP Not correctly reading the file

Tags: php, authentication

This is my code:

```
<?php
$pass = $_GET["pass"];
$user = $_GET["user"];
$next = false;
$file = fopen("info.txt", "r") or die("Something went wrong.");
// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($file)) {
  if ($next == true and $pass === fgets($file)){
      echo "true";
      $next = false;
  } else {
      echo "false" . "<br>";
      $next = false;
  }
  if (fgets($file) == $user) {
      $next = true;
  }
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

and this is `info.txt`

```
ch1ck3n
kodero1029
```

note that this is just a made up password

for example, we go to my website containing this code, https://ch1ck3n.com/login/auth/auth.php?user=ch1ck3n&pass=kodero1029

and it prints false TWICE.
I am making a login system using php and a simple txt document.
the php code reads the txt file lines one by one, and if a line matches the username, that means that the password is on the next line. but if you see, go to the website and it will print false twice.
the `$next` variable is to indicate that the next line is the password.

Comment: This is definitely 100% not secure. Anyone can open a text file from the browser. It's also not effecient at all, and your doing a bunch of extra work to do it like this. Why are you doing it like that?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton this is how Chickens *Do*

Comment: the txt file is forbidden on the website

Comment: I agree with the above, this is not a secure solution (regardless whether the text file is accessible through the site, there are other issues). Any particular reason you're taking this half-baked approach to security?

Comment: i don't get any errors

Comment: i have a favicon

Comment: Don't send sensitive information in URL as this is insecure with or without https: https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Maybe you should read the whole file first, and then perform your checks?

Comment: btw you could do away with the while by simply using [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), then match username, if username's index is an even number, check password. https://3v4l.org/LvtIK one line

Comment: correction https://3v4l.org/LFrlV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What's wrong?

Your issue is because:

```
  if (fgets($file) == $user) {
      $next = true;
  }
```

## Why is this wrong?

This is the only way that $next is true, but you have `$user = $_GET["user"] //ch1ck3n` but if you [**View the Manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) it states:

> **fgets**:
> Returns a string of up to length - 1 bytes read from the file pointed to by handle. If there is no more data to read in the file pointer, then FALSE is returned.

And see also:

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (***which is included in the return value***)

*(my emphesis)*

So you're return value from fgets is a string which includes the line ending, and you're comparing this to a text string `ch1ck3n` without a line ending. Therefore `$next` will never be true, so for each line of the file, the `if`/`else` statement will return the false option.

## Solution:

Strip line endings from your strings:

```
  if (trim(fgets($file)) === $user) {
      $next = true;
  }
```

The same will need to be done for all occassions you use `fgets`.

## Security Note:

As mentioned in comments, your method of approach for this issue re: security is absolutely the incorrect way of doing things. You should be using POST requsts or Database references or SESSION cookies to safely associate credentials data with the script.

> Don't send sensitive information in URL as this is insecure with or without https: [Link](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url)

[Comment by Felippe Duarte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754859/php-not-correctly-reading-the-file/64755079#comment114493005_64754859)

Comment: Based on the description the end result is a file with consecutive lines of usernames passwords. In that case the password line will have two `fgets` which may be a problem eventually (though not in this example)

Comment: @apokryfos I think to be honest that your answer was pretty much there, I don't see the double loop iteration you mention but you mentioned the key part being that the `fgets` returns the line endings which need to be trimmed off for string comparison.

Answer (score -1):

You are reading two lines per iteration of the loop. Since you only have two lines (maybe three?) that means in a single iteration you are done. Do this:

```
<?php
$pass = $_GET["pass"];
$user = $_GET["user"];
$next = false;
$file = fopen("info.txt", "r") or die("Something went wrong.");
// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($file)) {
   $line = rtrim(fgets($file)); //Newline is included in the fgets result
  if ($next == true && $pass === $line){
      echo "true";
      $next = false;
  } else {
      echo "false" . "<br>";
      $next = false;
  }
  if ($line === $user) {
      $next = true;
  }
}
fclose($file);
```

The reason that you get false twice is (probably) because you may have an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: It may be worth noting that trim automatically trips EOL characters by default so it's not needed to be defined.

Comment: plus one to you for `$pass === $line`  as well `:-)`.

Comment: @Martin it's a tricky one with trimming. If you don't specify then you might prevent people who want to have trailing spaces in their password, but I think that's generally common to trim those

Comment: @apokryfos I was thinking about writing a warning for that sort of issue but..... like mentioned above, there's enough things wrong with the code base I doubt it would make much odds...

Comment: Also the PHP_EOL value may not be the same as the text file end of line value!

Comment: @Martin yes, that's true. It will definitely be `\n` in the end (unless it's a very old Mac) but may or may not have `\r` before that resulting in a stray `\r` sometimes (which may be the reason why this didn't work)